# Is this divergent series, convergent?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, summation

Examining the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{nx}$ alongside its integral counterpart reveals insights into its convergence. Notably, the integral over intervals from $10^n$ to $10^{n+1}$ yields a constant value, not just for large $n$, but universally, which plays a crucial role in understanding the series' behavior.

**Integral Analysis**

The integral $\int_{10^n}^{10^{n+1}} \frac{1}{nx} \, dn$ consistently yields a constant value, independent of $n$. This can be demonstrated through calculation:

$$ \int_{10^n}^{10^{n+1}} \frac{1}{nx} \, dn = \left. \frac{\ln(n)}{x} \right|_{10^n}^{10^{n+1}} = \frac{\ln(10^{n+1}) - \ln(10^n)}{x} = \frac{n+1 - n}{x} \ln(10) = \frac{\ln(10)}{x} $$

This constant value sets an upper bound for the sum of the series' terms within each interval.

**Series Sum vs. Integral**

- **Series Terms Decrease**: The terms of the series, $\frac{1}{nx}$, decrease as $n$ increases, making their contribution to the total sum smaller.
- **Sum Bounded by Integral**: The sum of series terms from $10^n$ to $10^{n+1}$ is less than the integral over the same interval, as it only includes discrete values at integer steps, which are smaller than the continuous area under the curve.

**Proof by Contradiction for Convergence**

Assume that the series diverges. This would mean the partial sums of the series grow indefinitely. However, given that each partial sum within the intervals $10^n$ to $10^{n+1}$ is bounded by a constant value (the integral), this assumption leads to a contradiction. The series cannot diverge if its growth is consistently capped by a constant bound.

**Conclusion**

The constant value of the integral over any interval $10^n$ to $10^{n+1}$ of $\frac{1}{nx}$ provides a clear upper bound for the series' partial sums within those intervals. This bounded nature, in conjunction with the decreasing series terms, indicates that the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{nx}$ converges.

**PS:** Did I make a mistake in my explanation or interpretation of the convergence properties of the harmonic series and its partial sums? Please feel free to correct or clarify any points where you believe there might be an error.

Comment: You forgot that we have infinite many intervals $[10^n,10^{n+1}]$. In fact, the harmonic series IS divergent.

Comment: @Peter Graphically, as we move along the x-axis (increasing $n$), each successive rectangle representing a series term gets narrower (since the height, which is the value of $f(n)$, decreases). These decreasing heights of the rectangles imply that the series terms not only become smaller but also their contribution to the total sum diminishes. Hence, the sum of the series from $10^n$ to $10^{n+1}$ is not just bounded by the integral but also approaches zero as $n$ increases.

Comment: Firstly, $\frac1x$ is constant so factor it out of both the integral and the series. It's just a distraction. Also note that $\ln n$ is unbounded. It's insufficient for the tail of a series to approach zero to prove convergence. So smaller contributions is not enough.

Comment: @DiogoSousa Maybe , you are suprised that the harmonic series diverges since it does so very slowly , so slowly that one tends to believe it must converge if one deals with it the first time.

Comment: @CyclotomicField Since the integral (and thus the sum of the series) over each interval from $10^n$ to $10^{n+1}$ is bounded, we can find a bound $B$ such that:
   $$\sum_{n=10^k}^{10^{k+1}} \frac{1}{nx} \leq B$$

   for each $k \in \mathbb{N}$.

Given any $\epsilon > 0$, we can find an integer $m$ such that the total contribution of the terms beyond $10^m$ is less than $\epsilon$. Specifically, for $M = 10^m$, the sum of terms beyond $M$ can be bounded as follows:

   $$ \sum_{n=M+1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{nx} < \epsilon $$

Comment: This means that adding terms beyond $M$ changes the partial sum $S_N$ by less than $\epsilon$, indicating that the sequence of partial sums $S_N$ is becoming increasingly stable and is approaching a limit.

Comment: The partial integral is always $\frac{\ln(10)}{x}$ , independent of $n$ , so has a constant value. So the total integral is not bounded but tends to $\infty$. Even if it would strictly decrease , the sum could still well diverge.

Comment: @Peter I agree with you on that, but is the same appliable to the partial sums? Because supposably it becomes smaller and tends to 0.

Comment: For a series with positive entries $a_n$ , $a_n\to 0$  is necessary but not sufficient that the series converges. In fact, you can also split up the harmonic series in infinite many parts bounded from below , for example by considering the terms $2^n$to $2^{n+1}$ (or , which fits better to the integral from $10^n$ to $10^{n+1})$. Those parts are all bounded from below and do not tend to $0$.

Comment: @DiogoSousa that's not the case. The standard proof that the harmonic series is divergent is that we group the terms $2^n$ at a time like $ H_n = 1+\frac12 + (\frac13 + \frac 14) + (\frac15 + \frac16 + \frac17  + \frac18) + \dots$ then use that $\frac13 > \frac14$ and that $\frac15 , \frac16 ,\frac17 > \frac 18$so that each grouping sums to $\frac12$. This means $H_n > 1+ \frac n2$ and since $n$ approaches infinity the series diverges.

Comment: So what you did not consider is that with increasing $n$ , we sum up ever smaller summands , but also exponentially ever more of them.

Comment: Your integral of f(n) dn with bounds depending on the same n doesn’t make any sense whatsoever.